# Password hashing different salt with same username

Tags: c#, password-encryption, rfc2898

We introduced password encryption to our site.
The salt is calculated as shown below:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Username.ToLowerInvariant(),
           System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Wn.,G38uI{~6y8G-FA4);UD~7u75%6"), 10000);
string salt = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.GetBytes(25));
```

For most usernames the salt is always the same.
But for some usernames it changes at every call.
Can someone tell me what we are doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. There must be some other error in your code, for example when getting the `Username`. And by the way do not use Encoding.Default, it can change on a given system (but I don't think it's your problem). Please save Username to a variable if it's not saved already, and print it with the salt, run it a few times, and give us the results.

Comment: As I said, it works with most usernames. But if you try e.g. "heimrich" it's giving different values every time.

Comment: "heimrich" gives me "klvnm7SwKKAQuwNZ8oP/e5/9eLewcypL1w==" every time.

Comment: "heimrich" gives me "klvnm7SwKKAQuwNZ8oP/e5/9eLewcypL1w==" every time too, I think the problem is not here, check all your code

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. One time it came in trimmed and the other time the username had a space at the end.

Comment: My opinion: I hate trimming. Either make space a completely valid character so that I can even have a username like "a b" or make sure there are no spaces by means of validation.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a crypto PRNG to generate the salt and store it alongside the password?

Comment: I think this salting method is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using RFC2898DeriveBytes to hash the password itself as well, then @CodesInChaos is correct, what you're doing wrong is:

- Building the salt based off the username, instead of using a cryptographic PRNG to generate a fresh salt for each user.

  - You should use something like [the .NET RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate 8 to 16 (binary) bytes of random salt

    - For instance, from [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Example 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)

---

```
byte[] salt1 = new byte[8];
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
  {
  // Fill the array with a random value.
  rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1);
  }
```

---

- The salt should then be stored in the clear in your database alongside the password hash and iteration count (so you can change it), and probably a version code too (so you can change it again, i.e. your current calculated salt method is version 1, and the random salt is version 2).

  - Spending 20,000 iterations of PBKDF2 on the salt, rather than spending it on the actual password hash!
- 10,000 iterations for the first 20 bytes, since RFC2898DeriveBytes is PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1, and SHA-1 has a native 20 byte output
- 10,000 more iteration for the next 20 bytes, which is then truncated to only the 5 you need to get to a 25 byte output.
- This is a weakness, as the defender has to spend the time on the salt on every login, whether it's spent on the salt, or the password hashing.  The attacker has to spent that time once for each username, and then they are going to store the results and try **_illions (where _** is very large) of password guesses.

  - Thus, the attacker has a greater than normal marginal advantage because they can precalculate the salt, while you have to calculate it on the fly.

If you aren't using RFC2898DeriveBytes, another PBKDF2 implementation, BCrypt, or SCrypt to do the actual password hashing, then **that's** what you're doing wrong.

Trimming the username some, but not all of the time is entirely incidential; just make sure not to trim passwords before they're hashed.